# Deserialisation of YAML file with nested arrays in java

Tags: java, jackson, yaml, deserialization

I'm trying to deserialise a Yaml file in Java but facing issues as it has nested array format in it like in below example.

items.yml

```
ITEMS:
  - item1
  - item2
  - item3:
    - item4
    - item5
  - item6
```

I'm using Jackson here to deserialise it and it is working fine till item2 but while deserialising item3 it is throwing below exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class com.ymalParser.io.Item]: can not instantiate from JSON object (need to add/enable type information?)
```

I'm new to this deserialisation thing.
Can anyone help me with what I'm missing here.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: at that point, you probably want a mapping, not a series declaration. so `ITEMS` would have a mapping of `itemN` (no dashes!) to the values within it. Then you'd deserialize it to a `Map<String, List<Object>>`. Though continuing in using mappings you can see you can probably avoid lists for most things that aren't, well, basic data-only lists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating an array of simple types (item1, item2, item6). However item3 is a complex type.

```yaml
ITEMS:
  - item1
  - item2
...
```

Can be serialized in to `List<String>`

```yaml
ITEMS:
  - item1
  - item2
  - item3:
    - item4
    - item5
  - item6
```

Can not be serialized in to `List<String>` but `Map<String, List<Object>`.

Try this one:

```yaml
ITEMS:
  - item1: []
  - item2: []
  - item3:
    - item4
    - item5
  - item6: []
```

SECOND EDIT:

```java
public void test() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
    Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("test.yaml");
    InputStream input = resource.getInputStream();
    Map<String, List<Object>> list = mapper.readValue(input, new TypeReference<Map<String, List<Object>>>() {});
    mapper.writeValue(System.out, list);
}
```

Outputs:

```
---
ITEMS:
- "item1"
- "item2"
- item3:
  - "item4"
  - "item5"
- "item6"
```

Comment: Hi @Ghokun, tried what you have suggested Map<String, List<Object>> but got error stating ` Can not deserialize instance of java.util.LinkedHashMap out of START_ARRAY token `
Also, I can't modify the input YAML file, it'll be the format I mentioned above.

Comment: Sorry I typed curly brackets instead of squares.

Comment: What is the object that you are trying to deserialize into?

Comment: I'm trying to deserialize below object into List (if I'm getting Map than also its OK).  
UTILS:
  - SportsUtil (1.3.4)
  - NewsUtil (5.2.2)
  - FourWheeler (1.0.0):
    - CarUtil (1.3.1)
    - BusUtil

Comment: I can't modify the Yaml file like we mention with [ ], so I've to go through the original Yaml which I mentioned in the question itself.

Comment: I added a working example with your input, unmodified.

Comment: I've also done similar thing to solve this issue and it's giving me a Map of String (key) and ArrayList (value) and the value can further break into LinkedHashMaps for complex objects (item3), have a look to my code:  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
Map<Object,Object> myMap = new HashMap<Object, Object>(); try { myMap = mapper.readValue(new File("test.yaml"), HashMap.class); 
 for (Map.Entry<Object, Object> entry : myMap.entrySet()) { System.out.println(" key = "+entry.getKey()+" value = " + entry.getValue()); } }

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to provide an answer, just a small hint: see how your data looks like when converted to JSON:

```json
{
   "ITEMS": [
      "item1",
      "item2",
      {
         "item3": [
            "item4",
            "item5"
         ]
      },
      "item6"
   ]
}
```

The problem is that the elements of the `ITEMS` array are of different types: item1, item2 and item6 are strings, the third item is an object. In theory it's valid YAML/JSON, but deserializing it to a java object is problematic.

Comment: Thats correct @Mafor and this is where I'm stuck. I've tried some combinations for List and Map but none of them worked